# Wrapped Text Background Overlapping other text on different line

Tags: fonts, css

I'm having a problem with line-height + text background styling with css.

```
<style>
.wrap  {
    width: 70%; 
    line-height:0.9;
}
.hl {

        background-color: orange;
}
</style>
<div class="wrap">
       <span class="hl">
          Some content will go here which will be split into several lines depending of resolution (depending on width of wraper)
       </span>
</div>
```

I have dynamic text that wraps to multiple lines depending on browser width
The line-height for this text is less then 'normal'. When I apply a background color to the text, this background overlaps the bottom of the descender letters : g,p,y,q,j

[image]
It seems that the text is rendered in the browser such that the second/lower line of text (and its background color) is in front of the first/upper line of text, thus this second line's background is in front of the descender letter due to the line-height.

Each row gets a NEW background, because we are talking about an inline element.
I need to use inline element of course to get text background.
I need to solve this problem with css or JS, without changing the text line height of the text.

Additional infos:
I found a great answer here:
[Add padding at the beginning and end of each line of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994653/add-padding-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-each-line-of-text)

Answered by thirtydot (accepted answer right below question),
but if you check his live demo solution, and change line-height there to a smaller value, you will get the same problem as I have.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JnLje/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution: if you want to keep your line-height smaller than 'normal', instead of using a color background, use a repeating png image. Add a transparent area at the top of this png equal to the height of the overlap. :)

Answer (score 3):

Because your `line-height` is less and as I can see you are applying background color to your text, so increase your `line-height` and more over there is no unit specified, like `em` or `px` to your `line-height` property and btw no need of adding padding to it

Try this :

```
line-height:25px;
```

More Info: you need to give `inline-block;` because you are using span, you can simply use a `div` instead

Comment: Yes, but as stated in the question, we do not want to reduce the line height. 
I am looking for another solution. 

Also, why to use display: inline-block and div, as i already have <span> wich is inline element??

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text inside a span and set the span position as relative. This will do!

CSS:

```
.your-backgrounded-h1-class span { position: relative; }
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="your-backgrounded-h1-class"><span>Your Text!</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone unsatisfied with the current answers, I found a solution that allows any `line-height` and works for text breaking across lines. Use a gradient `background-image`. You may need to adjust the percentage for your needs.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 17%, orange 17%, orange);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `<span>` `display: inline-block;`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

.hl {
  font-size: 3em;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span class="hl">
          Some content will go here which will be split into several lines depending of resolution (depending on width of wraper)
       </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Testing would be different for sure after 6 years, having in mind that browsers changed - and rendering as well I suppose. At the time when question was asked, using image repetition was optimal (and probably only solution for specific issue I had - where line height had to be unchanged). I hope someone can try solution you posted and confirm does it work or not.

Comment: This seems good only if you're happy with the background being one big rectangle (which I currently see, using Firefox in 2023). 

But note that in the question, the screenshot shows the desire is for the background to sit unevenly (see how the right edges of the background of 'just' and 'hustling' do *not* do not line up with each other). 

Effectively it seems the desire is to form kind of a marker highlight effect underlining each word, not the block as a whole (so an 'inline-block' is not ideal here).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here… and obviously CSS has changed since the original poster asked the question, but this seems to work at least in recent Chrome + Firefox for me:

Basically you can use an outer `<span>` to set the background color, then use an inner `<span>` with the text, and set `position: relative` on the inner span to create a new stacking context. This results in the text of the inner span all rendering in a layer above the background color.

Here's a demo codepen:

https://codepen.io/techieshark/pen/abRZvvx

and the same thing but embedded below. Note the top shows with an undesired overlap and the bottom should show without.

```css
.padded-multiline { 
  line-height: 0.9;

  /* just for the demo */
  width: 400px;
  margin: 1.75em auto;
}

.background-color { 
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 220, .3);
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  
  /* 'clone' is what essentially copies the padding to the individual lines */
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  /* Needs prefixing! 
     see https://caniuse.com/css-boxdecorationbreak */
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.new-stack-context {
  position: relative;
}


/* just for the demo */
em {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #c0c;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #013968;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="padded-multiline">
  <span class="background-color"><em>How do I</em> add (horizontal) padding to subsequent lines of an inline text element? And use tight line height without background color obscuring text?</span>
</h1>

<h1 class="padded-multiline">
  <span class="background-color"><span class="new-stack-context"><em>How do I</em> add (horizontal) padding to subsequent lines of an inline text element? And use tight line height without background color obscuring text? <br/> Like this!</span>
</h1>
```

For reference in case anyone has a browser not rendering as mine is, here is how Chrome renders this in 2023:

[image: screenshot of codepen demo showing a non-working example followed by a working example. In the working example, the text is legible but in the non-working example the black background color under each subsequent line of text obscures the bottom half of the previous line of text]

The padding bit is inspired by "Adam Campbell’s box-decoration-break Method" documented/described by Chris Coyier here: https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

For completeness, here's similar code as demo above but updated to match more closely to the image from the original question:

```css
.padded-multiline { 
  line-height: 0.9;

  /* just for the demo */
  width: 800px;
  margin: 1.75em auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.background-color { 
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  color: black; 
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  
  /* 'clone' is what essentially copies the padding to the individual lines */
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  /* Needs prefixing! 
     see https://caniuse.com/css-boxdecorationbreak */
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.new-stack-context {
  position: relative;
}



body {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="padded-multiline">
  <span class="background-color"><span class="new-stack-context">Stop crying and just <br/>keep hustling</span>
</h1>
```

(Gold border included to help see what is happening.)