# Padding for background color of an inline text WITH text-indent

Tags: css, background, padding, text-indent

I am basically trying to do [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994653/add-padding-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-each-line-of-text/4995866#4995866) with a paragraph that contains text-indent, but can't get it because the display:inline won't allow text-indent. Any ideas?

Comment: Text indent has nothing to do with that

Comment: use display: inline-block; ,if i've understood your problem.

Comment: Wrap your paragraph with span which has a position relative a and left:10px if you want it to indent by 10 pixels

Comment: @Mr.Alien: the example I showed has nothing to do with text-indent, but what I wanted to do was apply text-indent to such example

Comment: @AndreaLigios: when I apply inline-block the background color stops being applied just to the text and stats being applied to the whole box

Comment: @jacek_podwysocki Adding postion:relative+left did work for moving the text, but for some reason it did't move the background color with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using pseudo elements

I've created a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmk4D/2) that uses `span` elements which are `inline` and then adds `before` and `after` pseudo elements to add additional spacing in front and at the end of each highlighted block of text.

In case you need to manipulate amount of that space adjust `font-size` within those pseudo elements and you should be good to go.

The trick is just:

```
.highlight {
    font-family: Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 48pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
    .highlight:before,
    .highlight:after {
        /* no-breaking-space (nbsp) entity */
        content: "\00a0";
    }
```

### Controlling space amount

Using appropriate character(s) in `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements one can actually control amount of added spacing down to individual pixels.

The best way is to use `thin space` which is in typographical terms 1/5 or sometimes 1/6 of an em. If we set `font-size` of these two pseudo elements to 6 pixels thin space should always approximate to 1 pixel width regardless of dimension discrepancies.

```
.highlight:before,
.highlight:after {
    content: "\2009";
    font-size: 6px;
}
```

Upper style definition will add 1 pixel of space on each side. If we put [5 thin spaces in content](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmk4D/3/), we'd get 5 pixel space...

Or use one thin space and add padding to it and control its width this way. Or even abolish any content and just use padding:

```
.highlight:before,
.highlight:after {
    content: "";
    padding: 0 5px; /* will give 10px space */
}
```

However one does it it's possible to control amount of space down to pixel granularity.

Comment: seems awesome, but I was looking for a HTML/CSS solution... I don't know much of JS...

Comment: Man... this is 100% CSS, no javascript involved. JSFiddle is just a online test platform to try code. You should accept this answer if this is what you wanted ;)

Comment: Ops, sorry for my ignorance... I'll implement it and see if it works!

Comment: by the way... what does the "\0000a0" mean? how can i alter it?

Comment: @merdesigner: it means exactly what the comment preceding it says... It's code for no breaking space. What would you like to change it to? you can put anything in this (i.e. "a") but I've deliberately put a **nbsp** in it, because it gets rendered by browsers without being *visible* (since it's a space). Normal space wouldn't do the trick because it's treated differently.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik It would be nice to be able to control how much  "padding" it adds to the text... is it possible? I've tried some variations, but most of them generated some serious bugs on most browsers...

Comment: @merdesigner: As said in my answer you can adjust `font-size` in `:before` and `:after` style definitions as long as they don't exceed your actual text size. But even then. You can use other characters that will get rendered. i.e. if you set `font-size` to `6px` and set content to **thin-space** (\2009) you'd get exactly 1 pixel space. duplicating content will get you pixel-control of the space. In this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmk4D/3/) I've added 5 pixels on each side.

Comment: Different entities you can use: thin-space (\2009), en-space (\2002), em-space (\2003), no-breaking-space (\00a0). But you'll have to learn what each of them represents. Oh and about that 6 pixel font size. I've seen that Chrome will not allow me to display lower size with currently selected font. So using thin space at 6 pixels size is 1 pixel space. Thin space in typographical terms is usually 1/5 (and sometimes 1/6) of an em. So when font size is set to 6 pixels (per em), thin space always approximates to 1 pixel regardless of discrepancies in width.

Answer (score 4):

Without br tag : demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/korigan/jzm3qu1q/1/

HTML

```
 <div class="wrap">
     <p class="highlight">
        <span class="text">Amet assumenda atque eos excepturi harum ipsa</span>
     </p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    width: 150px;
}
.highlight {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline;
    background: blue;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.highlight .text {
        padding: 4px;
        box-shadow: 4px 0 0 blue, -4px 0 0 blue;
        background-color: blue;
        box-decoration-break: clone; /* For Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, FYI I intend to use this snippet in my project (without attribution) assuming that is fine with you.

Comment: The Web is free. ^^

Comment: Thanks! I guess this example is pretty trivial anyway . Take care