# Background color only around text

Tags: html, css

I have an H1 in a div which is on more than 1 line because of fixed width of the div. I want to set the background color to H1 text only so that the background remains only behind the text (eg. if there is empty space in the end of the line, it should not use background color there).

**Also**, I need to set the left and right padding the text. I have tried to set the padding to the heading but it also does not work.

Here's what I'm trying to get:

[image]

I am trying to achieve this by setting the `inline` display for the H1, and setting background color, but it does not seem to work. Following is my HTML and CSS along with the demo.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget massa felis, at aliquam libero. </h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

h1{   
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 30px;   
    float: left;
    display: inline;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BQMXa/

Comment: A convoluted answer that is CSS-only is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994653/add-padding-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-each-line-of-text. They recommend that it may be better to do this with JavaScript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Remove** `float:left` in your `h1`

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BQMXa/4/)***

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is that i want to add the left and right padding to the heading, it does not seem to work.

Comment: @user1251698, setting `padding` works normally, e.g. `h1 { padding: 0 1em }` adds `1em` padding at the start and at the end. It seems that you want something else—probably something that you can achieve only by dividing the text in the heading into several elements, each to be displayed on a line of its own (with a fixed division into lines).

Answer (score 1):

The `float: left` is not necessary. Remove it.

Also, you may want to decrease the `line-height` so it looks like the demo (if you don't do this you will have blank lines under the text, which could be undesiderable).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How could I set the left and right padding in the heading text.

Comment: Please read this: [Inline elements and padding](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)